# Apache Calcite throws error when using COALESCE with untyped nulls only

Tags: sql, coalesce, apache-calcite

When runnning `SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL);` on Apache Calcite I get an error which tells that

> ELSE clause or at least one THEN clause must be non-NULL

This happens because `COALESCE` function is transformed to `CASE` expression and the latter is validated for whether at least one `THEN` or `ELSE` operand is not null. If all are `NULL`, then the error is thrown. This is motivated by reasons described in [a comment](https://github.com/apache/calcite/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/calcite/sql/fun/SqlCaseOperator.java#L205) found in source code:

> according to the sql standard we can not have all of the THEN statements and the ELSE returning null

One thing to note, is this query returns `NULL` when any of the parameters is explicitly cast, e.g. `SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR), NULL);`.

However I could not have found this anywhere. What I did found is [following](https://modern-sql.com/feature/case)  (see *'Abbreviations to Cope With null'* section, the emphasize  is mine):

> Coalesce returns the first not-null parameter (**or null, if all parameters are null**).

This statement, provided above, seems to be in accordance with [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rreffunccoalesce.html) and [PostreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-conditional.html) docs.

My question is, should `COALESCE` containing literal `NULL`s only work as per SQL standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether *anything* should work only according to the SQL standard might be a matter of academic debate, but it just is not how databases work. Every database -- as far as I know -- has quirks, extensions, and exceptions to the standard.  That simply is the fact of having different vendors provide such a language.

In most languages, I think that an untyped `NULL` ends up with a default type. I determine what it is by saving `select NULL` into a table (using whatever method is used for that database) and looking at the type.